# How to make Clojure respect `*assert*` variable?

Tags: clojure, assertions

I was to understanding that Clojure's `*assert*` variable could be used to turn off assertions, but nothing I do seems to works.

```
(defn foo [a]
  {:pre [(pos? a)]}
  (assert (even? a))
  [a])

(binding [*assert* false]
  (foo 1))
!! exception

(binding [*assert* false]
  (foo -2))
!! exception
```

Even to binding `false` when defining has same problems:

```
(binding [*assert* false]
  (defn bar [a]
    {:pre [(pos? a)]}
    (assert (even? a))
    [a]))

(bar 1)
!! execption
```

And then even to setting the variable direct does not working.

```
*assert*
is true

(alter-var-root (var *assert*) not)
*assert*
is still true
```

and

```
(var-set (var *assert*) false)
*assert*
is still true
```

So now I am not understanding what to do.  I am confused.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`*assert*` is a compile-time variable, not a runtime variable. It's meant to be used with `set!` as a top-level statement, not with binding (of course unless you call `eval` inside the binding).

Answer (score 4):

assert is macro defined in a way, that **assert** affects it's behavior at the expansion time.

if you try this code it will work as expected:

```
(binding [*assert* false]
   (eval '(assert false))
)
```

and your example with *var-set* should also work:

```
(var-set (var *assert*) false)
(assert false)
```

Comment: This does work. You could dynamically shut this off by testing for an environment variable.